# Derivative in mean

Tags: statistics, derivatives, means

I have one question about calculation rules for means.

Say I have an equation of the form
\begin{align*}
\langle H(a,b)  \rangle = \langle H_1(a,b) \rangle + \langle H_2(a,b)\rangle
\end{align*}
where $\langle ... \rangle$ is a mean (physical, i.e. integral over time / space).

Is then
\begin{align*}
\langle \frac{\partial H(a,b)}{\partial a}  \rangle = \langle \frac{\partial H_1(a,b)}{\partial a} \rangle + \langle \frac{\partial H_2(a,b)}{\partial a}\rangle
\end{align*}
also true? (a is a variable, but not the one considered in the mean integral, i.e not time / space).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, if

$$
\langle f(a)\rangle = \int{\rm d^3}{\bf x}~{\rm d}t ~f(a, {\bf x}, t)
$$

then

$$
\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}a}\langle f(a)\rangle = \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}a}  \int{\rm d^3}{\bf x}~{\rm d}t ~f(a, {\bf x}, t) =  \int{\rm d^3}{\bf x}~{\rm d}t ~\frac{\partial}{\partial a}f(a, {\bf x}, t)
$$